# setting an initial directory for the NGSPICE

Tags: ngspice, setup

After one launches NGSPICE, I want NGSPICE path, or current directory to be setup by me. How is that done?
I.e., instead of (for example):

`cd:\Users\NGSPICE\lv

source in.sp`

Just run:

`source in.sp`

Comment: Ngspice can't know what path you want unless you tel it so. Using `source x.sp` means the path is not specified and it defaults to the current path, wheerever that may be. So you have two choices: do as you did before, or write execute `source /path/to/x.sp`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have thought, but wanted to be sure. Thanks.